# calling javascript function from code behind doesnt work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {
    alert("it works");
}

</script>
<asp:GridView ID="gvWatchdogList" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="gvWatchdogList_PageIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No watchdog alerts active."
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50"
                    DataKeyNames="SpId,SpName,Subject,AlertDate" CssClass="mGrid" OnRowEditing="gvWatchdogList_OnRowEditing" OnRowCommand="gvWatchdogList_OnRowCommand">

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsEmail" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("EmailEnabled")) %>' OnCheckedChanged="cbIsEmail_OnCheckedChanged" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("HasMailAddress")) %>' AlternateText="Enable" CommandName="isEmail" AutoPostBack="True" CommandArgument="1" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void cbIsEmail_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "test();", true);

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "alert('Hello World');", true);

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "test", "test();", true);
}
```

I'm trying, as you can see, to call my test() function from code behind, but it doesn't work.

This is the result of all my attempts, but all has failed. Can anyone tell my why?

Comment: I've already searched as you can see from my attempts..

Comment: Why is not possible?

Comment: chek the answer i have given sorry for the wrong comments

Comment: check the output html where are the the scripts are rendered. be sure your function calling script registered after your function declaration.

Comment: Check the generated client html code and the corresponding your js code. Pls read this [link](http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2014/10/04/calling-javascript-code-behind-asp-net-using-c-how-it-works/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok
try this out

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFun1", "test();", true);
```

Comment: put your function test between headtag then try

Comment: first try it for a simple webform like on button click...because i think your code has some Mistakes.

Comment: i dont know why  this answer is not accepted its worked perfectly for me please try this first then...degrade the answer..